# All Links to the same page in the same color

Tags: html, css, web, anchor

I am the proud owner of http://rubin.cf, freshly loaded with [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com), and some custom css (google fonts). Is there a way to make all place-holder links (something) to be red?
I only want links which point to # to be red

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) like:

```
a[href="#"] {
    color:red;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/93Gb7/)**